# SQL query too big - Can I merge this?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, union

I have the query below which seems to work, but it really feels like I should be able to do it in a simpler manner.   Basically I have an orders table and a production_work table.  I want to find all orders which are not complete, meaning either there's no entry for the order in the production_work table, or there are entries and the sum of the work equals what the order calls for.

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
    SELECT o.ident, c."name" AS cname, s."name" as sname, o.number, o.created, o.due, o.name, o.ud, o.dp, o.swrv, o.sh, o.jmsw, o.sw, o.prrv, o.mhsw, o.bmsw, o.mp, o.pr, o.st
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN stations s on s.ident = o.station_id
    INNER JOIN clients c ON s.client_id = c.ident
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT p.order_id, SUM(p.ud) AS ud, SUM(p.dp) AS dp, SUM(p.swrv) AS swrv, SUM(p.sh) AS sh, SUM(p.jmsw) AS jmsw, SUM(p.sw) AS sw, SUM(p.prrv) AS prrv,
            SUM(p.mhsw) AS mhsw, SUM(p.bmsw) AS bmsw, SUM(p.mp) AS mp, SUM(p.pr) AS pr, SUM(p.st) AS st
        FROM production_work p
        GROUP BY p.order_id
    ) pw ON o.ident = pw.order_id
    WHERE o.ud <> pw.ud OR o.dp <> pw.dp OR o.swrv <> pw.swrv OR o.sh <> pw.sh OR o.jmsw <> pw.jmsw OR o.sw <> pw.sw OR o.prrv <> pw.prrv OR
            o.mhsw <> pw.mhsw OR o.bmsw <> pw.bmsw OR o.mp <> pw.mp OR o.pr <> pw.pr OR o.st <> pw.st

    UNION

    SELECT o.ident, c."name" AS cname, s."name" as sname, o.number, o.created, o.due, o.name, o.ud, o.dp, o.swrv, o.sh, o.jmsw, o.sw, o.prrv, o.mhsw, o.bmsw, o.mp, o.pr, o.st
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN stations s on s.ident = o.station_id
    INNER JOIN clients c ON s.client_id = c.ident
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM production_work p WHERE p.ident = o.ident
    )
) q ORDER BY due DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries in your UNION are almost identical so you can merge them into a single query as follows. I just changed the JOIN to the pw subquery to be a OUTER LEFT JOIN - which has the same reslut as your union because I incldued an additional OR clause in the WHERE statement to return these orders that dont have a record in the pw sub-query.

```
SELECT o.ident, c."name" AS cname, s."name" as sname, o.number, o.created, o.due, o.name, o.ud, o.dp, o.swrv, o.sh, o.jmsw, o.sw, o.prrv, o.mhsw, o.bmsw, o.mp, o.pr, o.st
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN stations s on s.ident = o.station_id
INNER JOIN clients c ON s.client_id = c.ident
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT p.order_id, SUM(p.ud) AS ud, SUM(p.dp) AS dp, SUM(p.swrv) AS swrv, SUM(p.sh) AS sh, SUM(p.jmsw) AS jmsw, SUM(p.sw) AS sw, SUM(p.prrv) AS prrv,
        SUM(p.mhsw) AS mhsw, SUM(p.bmsw) AS bmsw, SUM(p.mp) AS mp, SUM(p.pr) AS pr, SUM(p.st) AS st
    FROM production_work p
    GROUP BY p.order_id
) pw ON o.ident = pw.order_id
WHERE (o.ud <> pw.ud OR o.dp <> pw.dp OR o.swrv <> pw.swrv OR o.sh <> pw.sh OR o.jmsw <> pw.jmsw OR o.sw <> pw.sw OR o.prrv <> pw.prrv OR
        o.mhsw <> pw.mhsw OR o.bmsw <> pw.bmsw OR o.mp <> pw.mp OR o.pr <> pw.pr OR o.st <> pw.st
       )
OR  pw.order_id IS NULL
ORDER BY due DESC
```

Comment: This results in no rows being returned, unfortunately.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that in the first you wer joining on `o.ident = pw.order_id` and in the second you were using `p.ident = o.ident`. This answer will not work.

Comment: Actually, this does seem to work.  My colleague had simply blanked out the database right before I did my test.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the query I ended up with:

```
WITH work_totals AS (
    SELECT p.order_id, SUM(p.ud + p.dp + p.swrv + p.sh + p.jmsw + p.sw + p.prrv + p.mhsw + p.bmsw + p.mp + p.pr + p.st) AS total
    FROM production_work p
    GROUP BY p.order_id
), order_totals AS (
    SELECT ident, SUM(ud + dp + swrv + sh + jmsw + sw + prrv + mhsw + bmsw + mp + pr + st) AS total
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY ident
) 
SELECT o.ident, c."name" AS cname, s."name" as sname, o.number, o.created, o.due, o.name,      o.ud, o.dp, o.swrv, o.sh, o.jmsw, o.sw, o.prrv, o.mhsw, o.bmsw, o.mp, o.pr, o.st
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN stations s on s.ident = o.station_id
INNER JOIN clients c ON s.client_id = c.ident
INNER JOIN order_totals ot ON o.ident = ot.ident
LEFT OUTER JOIN work_totals w ON o.ident = w.order_id
WHERE w.order_id IS NULL OR ot.total <> w.total
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries of this form: Show rows which do not have a match in the other table.

Can be done like this:

```
select <columns>
from <table1>
left outer join <table2> on <join_condition>
where table2.column IS NULL
```

This will find rows from table1 which do not have anything in table2 matching the join condition.

For your summing query, I would do something like this...

```
select table1.order_number, total = sum(table2.order_amount)
from table1
left outer join table2 on table1.order_number = table2.order_number
group by order_number
having total < (some_number) OR total is null
```

That combines getting orders which have no matches, and getting orders with less than some total order_amount.

Comment: This one looks like it would be nice, but using HAVING means I'd have to group by every column I want returned, and that's not feasible.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Gargoyle You can group the `table2` in subquery and join `table1` to already grouped results.

Comment: Yeah, once you have your order numbers, if that's the primary key, you can use the order numbers to get whole rows. You can't calculate sums without some kind of grouping query, and that sounded like one of your requirements - "there are entries and the sum of the work equals what the order calls for"